# How to use ImageMagick with XQuartz

Tags: macos, imagemagick, xquartz

I am trying to create animated visualization in R and people say needs to install `ImageMagick`. However, it seems that current Mac no longer support x11, while ImageMagick just needs X11 server on Mac. [Install ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

I have also tried `brew install imagemagick --with-x11`, doesn't work and only returned so many errors.

Apples says need to use XQuartz to replace x11. I have XQuartz, but when I turned on it, typed the same commands [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), still give me the same error

> display: delegate library support not built-in '' (X11) @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/1891.

So, my questions is, **how to install and use ImageMagick with Mac XQuartz?**

Comment: Before you do any development on macOS, you need to install **Xcode command line tools**. Go to **AppStore** and download **Xcode** for free. Then, in Terminal, run `xcode-select --install`. Then try the **homebrew** installation again.

Comment: I have xcode installed

Comment: Good, I hope you have run `xcode-select --install` since any OS upgrades. Next, I would do `brew update; brew rm imagemagick; brew install imagemagick --with-x11`

Comment: Then run `identify -version` and check you get exactly the same version as when you run `brew info imagemagick`. Also `which convert` should tell you `/usr/local/bin/convert`

Comment: Did you "export DISPLAY=:0" in your .profile or .bash_profile file (without the quotes)?

Comment: Yes I tried that

Comment: Try starting `xclock &` before you use ImageMagick to make sure your X11 environment is working and able to display X11 windows.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I just got the chance to try what you said, it is in fact the solution to help me install `imagemagick`. And when I typed `xclock &`, XQuartz started to run as expected. Thank you very much! you can write it as solution, so that I can close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Note that things have changed a bit since I wrote this answer, Homebrew no longer supports installation options such as `--with-x11`. One possibility, pointed out in the comments by @MattWhite was to install **ImageMagick** interactively:

```
brew install imagemagick -i;
./configure --disable-osx-universal-binary --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-66 --disable-silent-rules --with-x11
make install
exit
```

Another option that occurred to me was that, rather than installing all of XQuartz, you could just add your own delegate that uses macOS's built-in `Preview` app and tell **ImageMagick** to use that, i.e. *delegate* to it. This means you can do things like:

```
magick SomeImage.png -crop 100x100+10+10 display:
```

For this to work, you need to find your `delegates.xml` file. I used this:

```
magick -list delegate | awk '/^Path/ {print $2}'
```

and mine is at:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick/7.1.0-16/etc/ImageMagick-7/delegates.xml
```

Then I edited that file and added a line very close to the end, but just above the last line like this:

```
<delegate decode="miff" encode="display" spawn="True" command="magick %i %u.png ; /usr/bin/open -a Preview %u.png"/>
```

That converts any file formats that **ImageMagick** knows into a PNG which the `Preview` app understands and should be able to represent most images, even those with 16-bit depth and transparency.

**Original Answer**

In general, to use **ImageMagick** with X11, you will probably be most likely to succeed if you follow the following steps:

**Step 1 - Install or update Xcode command line tools**

It is important that your developer tools are up-to-date, especially if you have updated your **macOS** version since setting them up originally. You can do this with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

**Step 2 - Ensure ImageMagick is correctly installed**

The easiest way to do this is first to ensure that old versions of ImageMagick are removed and cleaned up and that you then install (or re-install) with the latest version:

```
brew update                           # update homebrew itself 
brew rm imagemagick                   # remove old IM versions
brew install imagemagick --with-x11   # install latest IM version including X11 support
```

**Step 3 - Check**

If you have been trying for ages to install ImageMagick, you may have left some old versions lying around. It is important that you use the homebrew-installed version in `/usr/local/bin`, so check you are running the version you expect with the following:

```
which convert           # should report "/usr/local/bin/convert"
which magick            # should report "/usr/local/bin/magick"

identify -version       # should report same version as next command
brew info imagemagick
```

**Step 4 - Start X11**

Start X11, it is probably easiest to fire up `xclock`, which not only starts X11, but also checks everything X11 is running and your X11 environment is configured correctly:

```
xclock &
```

**Step 5 - Run ImageMagick X11**

Now you can test your **ImageMagick** configuration, without needing any test images as follows - since the `wizard:` image is built-in:

```
display wizard:
```

Comment: I would add just a bit to Mark's outline. I usually just start Xquartz itself before trying to display an image with ImageMagick. I also add "export DISPLAY=:0" to my .profile or .bash_profile file (without the quotes)

Comment: @fmw42 Hi Fred, Thanks for your top tips. By the way, you can highlight `code` in comments and answers by surrounding it with backticks, and do *italics* by surrounding with asterisks (no spaces) and finally you can **bold** text by surrounding with double asterisks.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I did not know that. I will have to study the markup docs.

Comment: When you are using `brew update`, if got error like "Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable", try command `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` to get the permission, then try `brew update`. After that, type `sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local` to change permission back

Comment: The `--with-x11` option isn't working for me. https://discourse.brew.sh/t/cant-install-imagemagick-with-options/4470

Comment: @dreeves **homebrew** has completely changed since I wrote this answer. AFAIK, packages no longer have options.

Comment: You can install it with brew in interactive mode: `brew install imagemagick -i; ./configure --disable-osx-universal-binary --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-66 --disable-silent-rules --with-x11; make install; exit`

Comment: @MattWhite Brilliant! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

I created a [Homebrew ImageMagick X11](https://github.com/tlk/homebrew-imagemagick-x11) formula that can be used like this:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick  # without X11 support
brew install --cask xquartz
brew install tlk/imagemagick-x11/imagemagick
```

Note that homebrew-core used to support [formula options](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#adding-optional-steps) such as `--with-x11` in order to enable a `configure` option of the same name. This is no longer the case as the Homebrew maintainer(s) [decided](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510) to remove formula options from homebrew-core formulas.

Comment: I install from source after installing all my delegates from MacPorts and do not get any error messages. I just install Xcode Tools and then XQuartz and do not include --with X11. That works to display images for me.